# Switching from full mode to archive mode

Tags: node, rpc, operation, archive-node

I have a `full node` with the last checkpoint at block `1077249`:

```
$ ./tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/checkpoint
{ "block":
    { "level": 1077249, "proto": 6,
      "predecessor": "BKo6N42jdPjfSVFg45K11X4uUQ4brs8jULqykcgCrerMntTGMFD",
      "timestamp": "2020-08-09T21:34:06Z", "validation_pass": 4,
      "operations_hash":
        "LLoZWi4QHrb8rqKELG1F48HfCiuKANZYcUW1WSYibo5uqMqDyNR7S",
      "fitness": [ "01", "0000000000067001" ],
      "context": "CoWRNfsAyGdMn5ShuQEhfp7PdACC6LWcXMLsP8GHu53fPRJ8aZPx",
      "protocol_data":
        "00016b9f3bc37f5c000000e37ce6f00eb61efb5047fdc3dc53d11dd42adbd8a6d4ebf1d3502803d82e1c14a98fba906c4ab948bc41eed159d8134bd56efd8a163b3162861687af2ac74232" },
  "save_point": 1077249, "caboose": 0, "history_mode": "archive" }
```

I'm trying to switch to `archive` mode such that, even if at one point a new snapshot is downloaded, I still have access to operations in all the blocks from block `1077249`.

So I ran with the `--reconstruct` option and got:

```
Aug 25 09:00:50 - snapshot: Starting reconstruct from genesis
Aug 25 09:00:50 - snapshot: Starting reconstruct toward the predecessor of the current head (BLCHRNoWRJ9LyJRELiNgAEuutmArWFrBni9DJzv1bhtMJxD3fNm)
Aug 25 09:00:50 - snapshot: Enumerating all blocks to reconstruct
Aug 25 09:18:25 - snapshot: Setting history-mode to archive
[waited around 24h then stopped process as no new output]
```

Now I can run the node with `--history-mode archive` option, but I still can't access blocks before the checkpoint:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8732/chains/main/blocks/1077248
$
```

Can I be sure that even if a new checkpoint is downloaded (unsure in which cases this could happen?), since now I'm in archive mode, I will always have access to blocks after `1077249`?

Comment: just fyi, a reconstruct will take days to finish, Last I heard from sone who did it, it takes about 3-5 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stopped the reconstruct before it was finished. Intel Core i7, 16GB RAM, 500GB SSD, took 4-5 days to complete.

Checkpoints are not "downloaded". They are made by your node, locally.

Once you complete the reconstruct, you will have access to *EVERY* block going back to block #1. Archive nodes will never garbage collect.

You should import a recent snapshot while doing the reconstruct, example:

```
./tezos-node snapshot import \
  --block=BLZ1YeTdFqCMm4f3djJpPYzNBzjgcDAeXFA4TAeX4QjXj3Tkg1B \
  BLZ1YeTdFqCMm4f3djJpPYzNBzjgcDAeXFA4TAeX4QjXj3Tkg1B.full --reconstruct
```

Grab a FULL snap from here: https://snapshots-tezos.giganode.io/

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. Hence a follow up question: is there any way to instruct my node to not further construct any new checkpoint after block 1077249? Any way to control that? So I can have a full node and still have access to all blocks after 1077249?

Comment: No, there is no way to control how many snapshots your node keeps. It is based on the network constant of PRESERVED_CYCLES + 2. Please mark the answer accepted if it's good.

Comment: That's really unfortunate as it forces you to compute the whole history if you want to keep more than PRESERVED_CYCLES + 2 amount of data :/

Comment: Agreed. You can open a feature request at gitlab.com/tezos/tezos